# FB.canvs.setAutoGrow() with https on fanpage tab

Tags: https, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've noticed that since this morning (maybe since yesterday night), the function FB.canvas.setAutoGrow didn't work anymore on a fanpage tab when i'm connected with https protocol.

Is it a facebook bug which will be solved soon ?

Comment: I've noticed the same thing. Seems like it's trying to load "https://check6only.facebook.com/ajax/v6.php?v=check6only&pingonly=false" which doesn't exists/is failing. My only assumption is that this is an error on their end that will hopefully soon be resolved. I'll let you know if I discover any workarounds.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/live_status

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a known issue:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/161462503988165?browse=search_4ff47b9a413f04323839980

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/394423653950625?browse=search_4ff47b759c3f78114111041